# how I integrate TortoiseSVN with the netbeans6.8?

Tags: netbeans, tortoisesvn, netbeans6.8

how I integrate TortoiseSVN with the netbeans6.8 ?

Comment: A tutorial on this topic can be found under the following address: http://wiki.netbeans.org/TutorialUsingSVNLocalRepository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TortoiseSVN is a standalone program.  NetBeans has its own SVN integration.  The two are unrelated, but you can use both of them interchangeably.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html 
http://tortoisesvn.net/

Answer (score 5):

Its easy to connect between Netbeans and tortoiseSVN. If you are using windows:

1. You need to install subversion for windows (http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/). After that you must set the path in win environment to include the subversion bin folder.
2. Install Tortoise client
3. Open Netbeans, and go to Windows > Versioning > Open the path where you install the subversion. or you can right click on your project folder and choose subversion.

Hope this help even its almost a year thread

Comment: From where to open `Windows > Versioning`? I'm using netbeans 8.1 and its not showing versioning window, instead its showing `Team->GIT/Mercurial/Subversion`

Comment: Do you have a comment for a newer version of NetBeans?  I don't see "Windows >Versioning" on Netbeans 8.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is install SVN - a version that is compatible with both Netbeans and Tortoise.  Tortoise is built for Subversion 1.6.6 and Netbeans supports who knows what? They claim support for Subversion: 1.4.x, 1.5.x, 1.6.x on their website but if you google it you will see they seem to have a lot of problems with it.

My experience was that any performance gain from IDE integration was offset almost immediately by having to constantly troubleshoot it everytime SVN was upgraded.  You will be better off doing your version control at the command line or just via Tortoise (which is lovely - I miss the shell integration now that I am using ubuntu and git).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you do. Perhaps you integrate NetBeans directly with Subversion? Subversion integration seems to be built in to NetBeans on my installation. TortoiseSVN integrates with Windows Explorer.

Comment: A note - if you're running a 64-bit JVM you can't use NetBeans internal SVN connector but have to set up paths to a SVN command-line client. You can get a binary build from CollabNet.